# pip install gives error after installing anaconda

Tags: python, django, anaconda

I am using Zsh. I had installed Anaconda a while back and presently when I tried to upgrade my pip I dot permission denied error even when used sudo. This is the result I got

[image]

Also when I tried to install django it gave error
[image]

[image]

Sorry for the less descriptive question. I am new to python and anaconda , so I don't know how to work with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the hint from the error message.
`Consider using the '--user' option.`

```
pip install django --user
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `conda install <package-name>`

Comment: Please use more description as to why this is needed.